# How can I implement a java method in to return the activity to the mainActivity?

Tags: java, android

I have my code for a simple activity to return to the main activity once the user clicks on the home button.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_greetings);

        // Set up onclicklistener for homeIcon imageview to go to back one activity
        ImageView homeIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home_icon);

        homeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is a java file for a single activity, greetings. I want this home button + functionality for many other activities, but I do not want to copy and paste. Should I make another java class, and implement the function inside of it? I tried, but it can not findviewbyid.

Comment: You should have a base class, which extends from an Activity, and do what you want for all the Activities, you can then extend from that class (BaseActivity)

Comment: For android studio, I am already extending AppCompatActivity. What should I do?

Comment: You can create an abstract class called BaseActivity and extend from AppCompatActivity, and then you can do all the stuff which you want to in you all other activities, then you can extend your others activities from BaseActivity and that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your code really hard understand why you can not find by id, but I can offer this way:

HomeButtonActivity.java

```
public class HomeButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button home_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_button);
        home_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(HomeButtonActivity.this, "Replace with your own action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity1.java

```
public class Activity1 extends HomeButtonActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

activity1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.HomeButtonActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    <include layout="@layout/home_button" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

home_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:text="home button"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am wondering one thing. setContentView(R.layout.activity_greetings);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  Why does setContentView have to go first? Before, I had super.onCreate() first, but the app would not run otherwise after extending my baseclass to appcompatactivity and my activity class to baseclass.

Comment: @EthanWatson, I wrote setContentView first because we need to create view and after that we can findViewById. If there are some problem with it you can create init method, insert it between onCreate and home_button in HomeButtonActivity and override it in Activity1

Answer (score 0):

create class e.g ReturnClass and create constructor for it, then pass Context as parameter e.g ReturnClass(Context context) then write

`Intent intent = new Intent(context , MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);`

from each activity you can call this class and pass activity to it , and ReturnClass return it to main activity